# IE Instance, DocumentCompleted Executing Too Soon

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I create an instance of IE outside my program, which the program finds and attaches to correctly. I set up my event handler and tell the program to advance to the login screen. The DocumentCompleted handle is supposed to fire when the web page is completely loaded, but mine seems to be firing before the new page has appeared.. The handle only fires once (meaning there is only one frame?).

This code executes fine if I modify it to work straight from the login page also.. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for any assistance :)

```
        Process.Start(@"IESpecial.exe");

        SHDocVw.ShellWindows allBrowsers = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (SHDocVw.WebBrowser ie in allBrowsers)
            {
                if (ie.LocationURL == "http://website/home.asp")
                {
                    loggingIn = true;
                    webBrowser = ie;
                    webBrowser.DocumentComplete += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
                    webBrowser.Navigate("http://website/logon.asp");
                    return;
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        //we are attempting to log in
        if (loggingIn)
        {
            mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)webBrowser.Document;
            mshtml.HTMLWindow2 window = (mshtml.HTMLWindow2)doc.IHTMLDocument2_parentWindow;

            doc.getElementById("Username").setAttribute("value", "MLAPAGLIA");
            doc.getElementById("Password").setAttribute("value", "PASSWORD");
            window.execScript("SubmitAction()", "javascript");
            loggingIn = false;
            return;
        }
```